# Drupal 7 Translate select all/none links in Better Exposed Filters

Tags: php, javascript, drupal, drupal-7, translation

How can I translate the texts "Select None" and "Select All" for "select all/none links" in Better Exposed Filter in Drupal7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From at least the Better Exposed Filters 3.0-beta3, the "Select All" and "Select None" links can be translated using the translate UI at `/admin/config/regional/translate/translate`.